# CasperJS Can't find variable $

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I'm trying to inject jQuery in my test but I get the following error:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

It is a ruby on rails application I'm trying to test, running on WEBrick.
Here's all of the code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ['jquery-1.9.1.min.js']   
});

//make sure page loads
casper.start('http://127.0.0.1:3000', function() {
    this.test.assertTitle('EZpub', 'EZpub not loaded');
});

//make sure all 3 fridges are displayed
casper.then(function() {
    //get fridges
    var fridges = $('a[href^="/fridges/"]');
    this.test.assert(fridges.length == 3, 'More or less than 3 fridge links shown');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Tests complete');
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the documentation it looks like you need to to use [evaluate()](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.evaluate) to get a reference to the page that is loaded

> Note The concept behind this method is probably the most difficult to understand when discovering CasperJS. As a reminder, think of the evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you're entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var fridges =  casper.evaluate(function(){
        // In here, the context of execution (global) is the same
        // as if you were at the console for the loaded page
        return $('a[href^="/fridges/"]');
    });
    this.test.assert(fridges.length == 3, 'More or less than 3 fridge links shown');
});
```

However, note that you can only return simple objects , therefore you cannot access jQuery objects outside of the evaluate (that is, you can't return a JS object), so you'd have to return just what's required to be tested, like the following

```
casper.then(function() {
    var fridgeCount = casper.evaluate(function(){
        // In here, the context of execution (global) is the same
        // as if you were at the console for the loaded page
        return $('a[href^="/fridges/"]').length;
    });
    this.test.assert(fridgeCount === 3, 'More or less than 3 fridge links shown');
});
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem. If I DO incorrectly spell the path I get the error: Failed injecting jquey-1.9.1.min.js client side, which I'm not getting with the current code.

Comment: @Cailen, put up a new answer

Comment: THANKS! Wrapping it up in evaluate() is the correct approach.

Comment: Note From Documentation: You can't inject scripts using the HTTP protocol, you actually have to use a relative/absolute filesystem path to the script resource

Comment: I came across this while searching and my problem was a bit more obscure. You need to pass only the function *object* to the evaluate call, do not execute the function in place. I knew this and had overlooked it in this case and it took a while to notice. Call `evaluate(function)`, not `evaluate(function())`.

Comment: @cookiecaper Yes, that is not an obscure problem, it's a very common mistake you'll likely never make again since you described it well :)