# How Do I use jQuery in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

```
casper.start(URL, function() {

    casper.page.injectJs('C:/Users/Mike/Documents/n1k0-casperjs-bc0da16/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
    var names = $('span.author-name');
    this.echo(names);
    this.exit();
}
```

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

What do I do? I've tried this too when creating the casper instance:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({

    // I've tried both commented lines below

    // clientScripts: ['C:/Users/Mike/Documents/n1k0-casperjs-bc0da16/jquery-1.10.2.min.js']
    // clientScripts: ['includes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js']
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS Can't find variable $](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981450/casperjs-cant-find-variable)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have evaluate the jQuery code in the browser context using <kbd>[casper.evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)</kbd>

> execute code as if you were using the browser console.

```
var nameCount = this.evaluate(function() {
    var names = $('span.author-name')
    return names.length;
});
this.echo(nameCount);
```

Comment: `return names.text();`

Answer (score 0):

Download the library then add its path using the clientScripts option:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    clientScripts:  [
        'path/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
    ]
});
```

And you are good to go with $(selector).