# phantomjs/casperjs count DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs, casperjs

I would like to count the number of, let's say, div elements with 'nice' class. I've got the selector `div.nice`, but don't know which casperjs class/method to use.

There is a [tester.assertElementCount](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#assertelementcount) method in fact, but is there anything that simply returns the number of elements?

Comment: I think you have to create your own function for this. It looks like the easiest way t do this is to check if the element exists and use the css ":nth-of-type(i)". I posted an answer below for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use jquery its fairly simple:

```
var count = $('div.classname').length;
```

Found an [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860928/how-do-i-use-jquery-in-casperjs) that seems to explain using jquery with casperjs, I have no experience with casperjs so I can't help much there.

Comment: `FAIL ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`. how can I "install" jquery into casperjs?

Answer (score 5):

Just

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.nice").length
```

Comment: hmm, so I don't have to do it inside `evaluate` function?

Comment: No, this is the `document` within the page evaluation context.

Comment: This returns `0` for me.

Answer (score 3):

One of the examples for CasperJS 1.1-beta3 involves [checking the number of Google search results for CasperJS](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#browser-tests). It references `__utils__.findAll()`, which takes a selector as its argument. It allows you to check the number of items returned using the `length` property available to any JS object:

```
test.assertEval(function() {
  return __utils__.findAll("h3.r").length >= 10;
}, "google search for \"casperjs\" retrieves 10 or more results");
```

I've never tried it, but it seems like this utility function can be used outside a conditional, and it will allow you to report the number of elements without using jQuery, as a previous answer recommended.

Comment: However, the `__utils__` functions are injected _in the remote DOM environment_, so they can only be accessed inside a function passed as a parameter to `casper.evaluate()` or `test.assertEval()`.

Comment: Yes that's right. What I meant is that using `__utils__` outside a conditional is just fine (i.e. as a general logging/debugging mechanism). I didn't mean to imply you could use it outside the `evaluate` or `assertEval` blocks. Can I update my answer somehow to make it clearer?

Comment: Maybe you could add a little example, like this one: `var count = this.evaluate(function() {return __utils__.findAll("h3.r").length;});`

Answer (score 3):

Casper provides [getElementsInfo](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html), you can use the attribute *length* to get the number of elements.
e.g.

```
casper.getElementsInfo('myElement').length
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use **assertElementCount** to assert the count of the elment

```
test.assertElementCount("div.nice", 1)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "how can I count these elements".

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the answers above to be helpful to my cause.

I think the goal was to count the number of elements without having to evaluate the js code in the page context, which could be frustrating overtime and have conflicting variables and functions.

Instead, it would be nice to leverage the casper automation context. This can be done with a combination of ".exists()" and the css psuedo-selector ":nth-of-type(i)"

The code below does this...

```
var counter = 1;          //set to one, for css selector setup

casper.then(function() {  //wait your turn
    //loop through our element
    while(casper.exists( 'div span:nth-of-type(' + counter + ')' )) {
        counter++;        //count the results
    }
});
```

You could make this a function and pass in all the arguments, or just copy and paste it as a step.

Best part, you could follow it with a repeat statement for a pretty cool loop.

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.repeat(counter, function() {
        console.log("Another one - item #" + counter);
    });
});
```