# CasperJS doesn't find jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I'm using jQuery selectors for casper.js scraping. I understand that it's necessary to [place the jQuery calls inside `casper.evaluate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861219/3399416).

The **problem** is that in the *last* of these following three functions, a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` is raised. The first two work absolutely fine.

```
// On main page, scrape links to sub-pages.
function getLinks() {
    var links = $('li.ds-artifact-item a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

// On main page, scrape sub-pages' titles.
function getTitles() {
    var titles = $('li.ds-artifact-item a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(titles, function(e) {
        return e.innerHTML;
    });
}

// On sub-page, scrape document description.
function getDescription(){
    var descriptions = $('td.label-cell:contains(date)');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(descriptions, function(e) {
        return e.innerHTML;
    });
}
```

Here's the rest of the script, with the unimportant details obscured. Note that `anotherValidPage` is a valid URL which returns HTTP 200 (success).

```
var links = []; var titles = []; var descriptions = [];

casper.start(validPage, function() {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    titles = this.evaluate(getTitles);
});


casper.then(function() {
    // echo results
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - '));
    this.echo(titles.length + ' titles found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + titles.join('\n - '));
    });

casper.thenOpen(anotherValidPage, function(){});

casper.then(function(){
    // This call is the problematic one.
    descriptions = this.evaluate(getDescription());

    this.echo(descriptions.length + ' descriptions found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + descriptions.join('\n - '));
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: instead of calling `this.evaluate(getDescription())` I had to call `this.evaluate(getDescription)`, since I guess I was executing the function instead of passing it as an argument, whoops.