# How to set initial variables in relay modern?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs

started relay at learnrelay.org, from the tutorial the code to set initial variables https://www.learnrelay.org/queries/variables/ is like this:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(
  ListPage,
  {
    initialVariables: {
      sortOrder: 'id_DESC'
    },
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Viewer {
          allPokemons (first: 1000, orderBy: $sortOrder) {
```

we usually assign variables in relay classic like this, but this code throws an error in relay modern and I don't know why?

```
export default createPaginationContainer(TodoList,
  initialVariables: {
    first: 10,
  }, 
  fragments: {
  viewer: graphql`
    fragment TodoList_viewer on User {
      todos( # we need to expose todos on user so we can check if todo text already exist and sync in database 
        first: $first 
      ) @connection(key: "TodoList_todos") { #assign a key of connection that can be used shared updater
```

Comment: There's not enough information for us to help. What's the error message? What debugging have you done? Also provide a little more context on what client you're using, who's calling this `createPaginationContainer` function

Comment: @JuanMendes updated the question, the error is on line 6:   viewer: graphql`

Comment: @JuanMendes already imported createPaginationContainer, but I still cannot assign initial variables

Comment: Properly asking a question will make others want to help you. Nobody wants to waste their time digging into your question. Make it easy for us to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ I specifically asked you for an error message and all you gave me was a line number. Don't just give me an error message either, look at the link above and make your question more self contained. Lastly, a screen name of "i am newbie" doesn't mean that you don't have to do due dilligence

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry I forgot to state the error, it's webpack build failed on line 6, I thought I am clear because I provided a code of setting initial variable before the update, and the code after the update looks similar

Comment: What I am saying is that if you provide enough context, even those that don't know the exact technology (graphql) may be able to help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981450/casperjs-cant-find-variable/15981541#15981541, I had never worked with CasperJS but I was able to help because the code was self contained and had enough context for me to do a search and find the answer.

Comment: yes, I understand your point, I appreciate the links you provide, will take note of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `initialVariables` in Relay Modern - [see this link in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/upgrading-setvariables.html). 
 Note that as of now, the documentation for migrating away from these functions is extremely brief.

If you're working on this right now, there's a [pending update](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/1771) to the [RefetchContainer documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/refetch-container.html) that shows how to properly fetch and refetch your view based on variables.

If you're only using the variables for pagination, [check out PaginationContainer](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/pagination-container.html).